# Redirect to another controller with an argument in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller :

```
public ActionResult Giris(string KimlikNo)
{
    return RedirectToAction("YeniBelge");
}
```

I have another controller :

```
public ActionResult YeniBelge(string KimlikNo)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

How can I pass KimlikNo's value to YeniBelge controller? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it using a route value. I assume you mean another method, not another controller

```
return RedirectToAction("YeniBelge", new { KimlikNo = KimlikNo });
```

If the methods are in different controllers, then use

```
return RedirectToAction("YeniBelge", "OtherControllerName", new { KimlikNo = KimlikNo });
```